# Wordpress - Highlight text in a textbox

Tags: wordpress

I just installed wordpress. I have created a post and I am trying to display a bit of text in a hightlighted textbox. Similar to the screenshot below. I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Do I need a specific plugin to do this  ? or can I do it out of the box. I tried installing a plugin called "SyntaxHighlighter Evolved" which seems to work fine for PHP etc... but the below is plain XML and it just seems to bugger it up. Besides I only want to text to be highlighted I dont really care if its displayed as code or not.

Please help, I wil be so greafull.
[image: Highlighted text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way to get this done.

Wrap your code in the following

> [p style="padding: 2px 6px 4px; color: #555555; background-color:
>
> ## eeeeee; border: 2px solid #dddddd;"] CODE GOES HERE [/p]

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, this should work:

```
[xml]PUT CODE HERE[/xml]
```

Here's the list of available languages:
http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/brushes/